# Laravel and opencart htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, opencart

I have a laravel site that client now wants opencart on the same domain, but running in the www.example.com/shop directory. I have put opencart in the public folder but I am having trouble with making the htaccess file redirect.

This is what I have done so far, but it just routes to laravel with route not found rather than going to the opencart folder. This is run on wamp at the moment, laravel works fine.

```
#if not from another platform(opencart) then load laravel
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#redirect to open cart directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ shop/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Did you change the `RewriteBase /` in Opencart's `.htaccess` file to `RewriteBase /shop/`? Your `.htaccess` file (which you have posted here) seems to me little bit confusing... IMHO the rewrite for OC is not needed at all...

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.htaccess` to this one.

```
#if not from another platform(opencart) then load laravel
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#redirect to open cart directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /shop/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```